# Getting the data out of the data Formview

Tags: vb.net

I have an ASP pg with a formview list control on it that hooks up to a sql database customer table

I want to access the customer name outside the form.

How do I:

A) access the bound text box in the form view template?  Something like Text1.text=formview1.customername.text (that doesn't work but that's the kinda thing)

B) access the database field in the table that the sqlsource connects to to feed the formview

Really appreciate the help.  I bet it's easy to do but I'm just not getting there.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use the [DataBinder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.aspx).  For example:

```
<asp:formview id="formViewContainer" ... other code>
    ..... formview code .....
    <%# Eval("CustomerName") %>
    ..... more formview code .....
</asp:formview>
```

Then to access "CutomerName" outside of the formview use the [DataBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.aspx) as follows:

```
<asp:textbox id="customerName" runt="server" 
             text='<%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(formViewContainer.DataItem, "CustomerName") %>' />
```